# How to Enable IPV6 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (Cloud Google VPS)

Tags: windows, vps, ipv6, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Cloud Google VPS. Since it's free, I am testing some Windows Server with 2012 R2 OS, but having a problem enabling IPv6 IP Address.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFcc.png]

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Google supports IPv6 inside their cloud platform. All references to IPv6 talk about deploying a proxy or load balancer with IPv6 at the edge, but then connecting to resources inside the cloud platform via IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine doesn’t support IPv6 for instances at this time. Google is committed to implementing IPv6 everywhere, so this issue is going to be addressed. For now there is a [FR (Feature Request)](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904387) opened and in progress, you might track its progress via this Public Issue Tracker link.